# "Groupby" functionality on index of `static_frame.Series`

Tags: python, static-frame

I have a `static_frame.Series`, like so:

```
import static_frame as sf
import numpy as np

colors = ('red', 'green')
shapes = ('square', 'circle', 'triangle')

series = sf.Series(np.arange(6), index=sf.IndexHierarchy.from_product(shapes, colors))
```

I want to be able to perform some "groupby" function, like summing all like-color values together. With a `pandas.Series`, I could do this:

```
agg_series = series.groupby(level=1).sum()
```

How do I do the same with `static_frame`?

I looked under [the group iterator functions](https://static-frame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_iter.html#id1), but those don't let you group by index hierarchy levels. I could probably turn this into a `sf.Frame`, group by the index columns, then cast back to a `sf.Series`; but that's a lot of effort, esp. compared to the above `pandas` equivalent.

If there's no straight-forward way to do this, I'll post it as a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: (Sorry for the "pandas" tag; I don't have the required 1500 reputation to make a new tag for "static_frame". Someone please correct this.)

Comment: @ayhan thank you for the tag!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a new type of group iterator which supports both group iteration based on index values, as well as function application to those groups. (This was released with static-frame 0.3.1, of which I am an author.)

With an `IndexHierarchy`, both single integers, as well as an iterable of integers, can be used for selecting on or more index levels to group with.

See the example here:

```python
>>> colors = ('red', 'green') 
>>> shapes = ('square', 'circle', 'triangle')
>>> s1 = sf.Series(range(6), index=sf.IndexHierarchy.from_product(shapes, colors))
>>> s1
<Series>
<IndexHierarchy>
square           red   0
square           green 1
circle           red   2
circle           green 3
triangle         red   4
triangle         green 5
<<U8>            <<U8> <int64>

>>> s1.iter_group_index(0).apply(np.sum)
<Series>
<Index>
circle   5
square   1
triangle 9
<<U8>    <int64>

>>> s1.iter_group_index(1).apply(np.sum)
<Series>
<Index>
green    9
red      6
<<U5>    <int64>
```